# Realtime Database Security Rules for a web app

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am facing some issues playing with security rules in Firebase Realtime Database. Here is the situation:

- I have four collections: CollectionOne, CollectionTwo,
  CollectionThree, Users.
- And I have a small web page using these collections in various ways.

To begin with my security rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

At this point the web page is working fine. But the security rules are very unsafe. For the next step I set the rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

At that point the web page is still working as expected; I can view the data.

For the second step of fine tuning my rules, I set them as follows:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": false,
    "CollectionOne": {
      ".read": true
    },
    "CollectionTwo": {
      ".read": true
    },
    "CollectionThree": {
      ".read": true
    },
    "Users": {
      ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```

Here things no longer work as I expect:

The web page is not displaying any contents. I was still expecting the data to be visible.

Can someone explain why my rules are not working?

In a previous project I had set similar rules and it was working.
I can't see why this time it doesn't.

Comment: Security rules on their own don't do anything; only once you execute code against them do they become active. Please edit your question to show the [minimal code that isn't doing what you expect it to do, as well as the exact error message and complete stack trace you get](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Indeed, I needed to take a slightly different approach, due to the way I was querying the DB. I changed my data structure and the rules to fit the three collections in one set and it now works. I put my solution as an answer, feel free to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I ended up solving my problem. I changed my data structure and the rules to fit the three collections in one set. These are the new rules:

```
{
 "rules": {
   "TheCollections": {
       ".read": true,
       "CollectionOne": {
         ".write": "(auth!=null)"
       },
       "CollectionTwo": {
         ".write": "(auth!=null)"
       },
       "CollectionThree": {
         ".write": "(auth!=null)"
       },
   }
   "Users": {
     ".read": true
   }
 }
}
```